# Extra built up mold on brie cheese

Tags: cheese, mold, brie

I had a brie cheese in the fridge and got extra mold built up on the area where it was cut. Note that I had other food getting moldy in the fridge, but those were dark mold. The brie got a white mold, similar the one of the rind.
Is it safe to cut and eat? I'm coming out of a stomach gripe, so would not like to take a risk.
Thank you! [image]

Comment: Three separate aspects of your question would make me prescribe a total fridge clean, followed by a complete change in your cross-contamination prevention methods. Throw out everything not fresh & sealed for starters.

Comment: If you don't want to take the risk....why bother?  Seems like a good enough reason to discard.

Answer (score 6):

....Honestly I'm guessing it is the penicillium candidum (the normal white brie mold), but you can't know from looking at the picture. Common sensically speaking, if the brie was properly wrapped up, then the other molds in your fridge are unlikely to have gotten a foothold on your brie, BUT it is possible for the other completely unknown molds in your fridge to have taken up residence without having formed visible colonies. So from that perspective, better safe than sorry.

Personally, as someone with a healthy immune system, if it were a fairly pricey brie, I'd cut off and toss the exposed edges of the brie, wrap it in puff pastry or pie crust, and bake it. But if it were fairly cheap, I'd probably toss it, and I hate wasting food and money.

Comment: If it was from *my* fridge, I'd just eat it as it is, because I could be 90% certain it's not come from anywhere else. As the OP already has at least 2 independent outbreaks & the chunk we're being shown is on a plate with 2 visible contaminants already, I'd play safe & bin the lot.